# How to run cronjobs on local files on cloudControl PaaS?

Tags: cron, worker, cloudcontrol

On cloudControl, I can either [run a local task via a worker](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Data%20Processing/CloudAMQP) or I can run a [cronjob](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Deployment/Cron).

What if I want to perform a local task on a regular basis (I don't want to call a publicly accessible website).

I see possible solutions:

1. According to [the documentation](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Add-on%20Documentation/Deployment/Cron),

   > "cronjobs on cloudControl are periodical calls to a URL you specify."

   So calling the file locally is not possible(?). So I'd have to create a page I can call via URL. And I have to perform checks, if the client is on localhost (=the server) -- I would like to avoid this way.
2. I make the worker `sleep()` for the desired amount of time and then make it re-run.

   ```
   // do some arbitrary action
   Foo::doSomeAction();

   // e.g. sleep 1 day
   sleep(86400);

   // restart worker
   exit(2);
   ```

Which one is recommended?
(Or: Can I simply call a local file via cron?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is not possible, because the url request is made from a seperate webservice.
You could either use HTTP authentication in the cron task, but the worker solution is also completely valid.

Just keep in mind that the worker can get migrated to a different server (in case of software updates or hardware failure), so do SomeAction() may get executed more often than once per day from time to time.

Comment: Adding to this, you can always use the cron Add-on to trigger an http request, and use that start a worker via the API. Regarding the worker restarts, if a worker is restarted due to a e.g. a node failure it keeps the same worker id. The worker id is available in the environment. You can use this to implement a locking mechanism, if it's important the task is never run more than once for example.

Comment: Would you have any documentation or howtos available for these scenarios?